# Android question mark after variable

Tags: kotlin

I sometimes see statements like `somevariable.value?.add()` What purpose does the question mark serve?
(Sorry, at the time of post I had no idea this was Kotlin, I thought it was java)

Comment: This is not Java code. It's Kotlin.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Kotlin treats `null` as something more than the source of null-pointer exceptions.

In your code snippet, `somevariable.value` is of a "nullable type", such as `MutableList?` or `Axolotl?`. A `MutableList` cannot be `null`, but a `MutableList?` might be `null`.

Normally, to call a function on an object, you use a `.`.

One option for calling a function on a variable, parameter, or property that is
of a nullable type is to use `?.`. Then, one of two things will happen:

- If the value is `null`, your function call is ignored, and `null` is the
  result
- If the value is not `null`, your function call is made as normal

So, in your case:

- If `somevariable.value` is `null`, the `add()` call is skipped
- If `somevariable.value` is not `null`, the `add()` call is made on whatever `somevariable.value` is

Comment: one possibly should also take `!!` for `@NonNull` into account.

Comment: there is a book, already: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

Comment: Thank you - I haven't delved into Kotlin yet even though I know I should be so this check threw me off. I can clearly see the value of Kotlin.